# What is the meaning of 'it is to'?

Tags: meaning, pronouns

This is a sentence I came across.

> What, then, is the solution? **It is to** explore what this book itself says about this topic.

I wonder what the meaning of the bolded words. Specifically, what does 'it' refer to?

Comment: Pronoun ***it*** refers to / stands in for the previously mentioned noun ***the solution***.

Comment: I see. Thanks. But I am still confused because the noun 'solution' and the phrase 'to explore something' do not have similar classes of meaning.

Comment: Consider *To live **is** to suffer.* Obviously there's something "nouny" about those first two words, since they're able to serve as the "subject noun" for the singular verb form ***is***. By the same token, ***My fate** is to suffer*, and ***The solution** is to explore*. Does that help?

Comment: That's clarifying explanation. I now understood well. The concept of 'solution' in my native language refers mostly to written or spoken answers to a problem. So I could not think of the possibility that 'solution' can include 'action' for finding an answer. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't know if my line of thinking would help you - but since it apparently *did* help, I've copied it into an actual answer, which may help other people in future.

Comment: When you see an infinitive used as a noun, you can replace it with a gerund and the meaning is the same: “It [the solution] is to explore [exploring] ...”

Comment: You have a flat tire. What, then, is the solution? It is to repair or replace the tire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun ***it*** refers to / stands in for the previously mentioned noun ***the solution***.

Consider an utterance like ***To live** is to suffer*. Obviously there's something "nouny" about those first two words, since they're able to serve as the "subject noun" for the singular verb form ***is***.

By the same token, ***My fate** is to suffer*, and ***The solution** is to explore*.